# How to handle identity column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, ado.net

I created a table in  a database with identity column called id . when i delete data from this table and add new data the id column is still increased by 1 , i need to make this column start increasing from the last id inside this table not the deleted one what should i do ?

this is the datagridview with some records:
[image]

this is the  delete code

```
if (comboBoxdelete.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MOHAMEDSAFWAT;Initial    Catalog=Card;Integrated Security=True";
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [Employee] WHERE [int]=@id1";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id1", comboBoxdelete.SelectedItem);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    load();
    View();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Please Insert  ID First");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Identity column (in SQL-Sever) is handled by by RDBMS. It will be increased any time you add some row to the table, when removing rows the RDBMS will not rollback the underlying sequence of the identity column.
Id or primary key of your tables are for internal usage of your application. normaly you must not show them to the user.
do not use the id column as row number for end user (as any thing is showing to the user will be compromizer to be requested to be updated or deleted) 
By the way lets think we need to implement the id column manually to full fill your requiment.
We can use a simple approach: When adding any new row first we call a select to fetch the new id:

```
SELECT ISNULL(count(*),0)+ 1 as newid from Employee
```

We will have the new id. 
know the delete scenario, think that we have

```
Employee1-->id = 1 
Employee2-->id = 2 
Employee3-->id = 3 
Employee4-->id = 4
```

Now we delete `Employee2` so what is needed to be done? 
We need updates(after detecting rows to be updated) like this, to achieve your requirement:

```
  Update Employee3 set id = 2 
  Update Employee4 set id = 3
```

For all rows in the table!
It will not work in large amount of data, id is the primary key when updating, all child records must also be updated, re-indexing, table locking and ... will be inevitable.
All this is because the id column is being showed to the user and you need that to be shown sequentially.
Use another non key column like `Employee-Number` or a UI level column like `RowNumber` for these scenario and do not show your primary key to the user.